# What to use django user object or create a user model?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-users, user-object

I want to create a user for my website that can submit a request form
but I'm wondering which is suitable choice :

1. To use a user object that already created
2. Create a user model from scratch

**Note**: I will let the users to login in my website from the active directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only If your User object need more than primary attributes like Nick Name, Skype or Phone No, etc... whatever.

In this case you can extend to use your own User object by creating ...

```
class Profile(Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    nike_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

For more details `User Object`

Comment: so Its possible to use user object for user that access the web app not only the usera who in admin page

Comment: I think you're referring to a [custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#auth-custom-user). <-- That link is the new recommended way of doing it.

Comment: @rnevius No... See OP got confuse about User object that's why the answer clarify. But I too aware that `AUTH_USER_MODEL` is best for Substituting user object.

Comment: @Hannah if the answer suits you then tell community to accept the answer

Comment: @Hannah Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/tour . In my answer left side one tick mark will be there. Please click the tick to accept and also you will get 2 reputation.